# Get unique data with multiple column using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm new to the google app script and also javascript. Need some help on this topic.

**Current Data:**

Week1   USA
Week1   Netherlands 
Week1   South Africa 
Week2   Turkey
Week2   UK
Week2   USA 
Week1   USA 
week2   UK

**Modified to:**  
Week1   USA            2 
             Netherlands    1 
             South Africa   1 
Week2   USA            1 
            UK             2 
            Turkey         1

Comment: Seems as though a pivot table might be adequate and a script is not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. Just copy the code into the script editor and save it.
Then you can use it in your spreadsheet like this: `=countCountries(A1:B8)`

```
function groupValues(array2D) {
  var result = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++) {
    if(!(array2D[i] instanceof Array) || array2D[i].length < 2) throw new Error("two columns are needed");
    if(!result[array2D[i][0]]) result[array2D[i][0]] = [];
    result[array2D[i][0]].push(array2D[i][1]);
  }
  return result;
}

function countValues(array) {
  var result = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(!result[array[i]]) result[array[i]] = 0;
    result[array[i]] = result[array[i]] + 1;
  }
  return result;
}

function toArray(o) {
  var result = [];
  for(key in o) {
    result.push([key, o[key]]);
  }
  return result;
}

function countCountries(range) {
  var grouped = toArray(groupValues(range));
  grouped.sort();
  grouped.forEach(function(values) {
    values[1] = toArray(countValues(values[1]));
  });
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < grouped.length; i++) {
    result.push([grouped[i][0], grouped[i][1][0][0], grouped[i][1][0][1]]);
    for(var j = 1; j < grouped[i][1].length; j++) {
      result.push(["", grouped[i][1][j][0], grouped[i][1][j][1]]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  =QUERY(A14:B21,"Select A,B,Count(B) group by A,B")
```

Comment: It takes the first data table in OP's post - Takes two columns (A&B) and counts the number of occurrences of B(Total 3 columns) and it's grouped together by A,B(i.e.,  For every unique instances of A&B, Count of B is done)--> Gives the second table that OP needs.